# Extract data from website using SAS

Tags: sas

I want to extract data from a website which having login & passwords, Can anybody help me how to extract using SAS, I tried with so many example using urls but its not working and giving a error message as **"ERROR: Host name www.seer.cancer.gov not found"**. I am having SAS EG (BASE SAS), Please see the example below:

Example1:

```
 filename seercode URL "http://www.seer.cancer.gov/siterecode/icdo3_d01272003/index.txt";
data siterecode;
infile seercode truncover;
input @1 bigline $char256.;
run;
```

Example2:

```
FILENAME SOURCE URL "%STR(http://www.usatoday.com)" DEBUG;
    DATA SOURCE1;
    FORMAT WEBPAGE $1000.;
    INFILE SOURCE LRECL=32767 DELIMITER=">";
    INPUT WEBPAGE $ @@;
    RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proxyserver in front of your browser you might need the PROXY=proxyurl option.
You can find the proxyurl either directly in your browser or by looking at the wpad script that many sites use to store information about what sites should use what proxyserver. The script can normally be found at this url:

```
http://wpad/wpad.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'user' option in the FILENAME sas statement, please take a look here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000223242.htm .

```
filename foo url 'https://www.b.com/file1.html' user='jones' prompt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code for both examples. It run absolutely fine (see log files below). I would suggest that you should try to specify PROXY and PUSER and PPASS options. For example, in your first code:

```
filename seercode URL "http://www.seer.cancer.gov/siterecode/icdo3_d01272003/index.txt" proxy='http://proxy.com' puser='login' ppass='pws';
```

See more information here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000223242.htm

Here are the log files for
Example 1:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 42         ;
 43          filename seercode URL    "http://www.seer.cancer.gov/siterecode/icdo3_d01272003/index.txt";
 44         data siterecode;
 45         infile seercode truncover;
 46         input @1 bigline $char256.;
 47         run;

 NOTE: The infile SEERCODE is:
       Filename=http://www.seer.cancer.gov/siterecode/icdo3_d01272003/index.txt,
   Local Host Name=localhost.localdomain,
   Local Host IP addr=::1,
   Service Hostname Name=www.seer.cancer.gov,
   Service IP addr=63.236.108.164,
   Service Name=httpd,Service Portno=80,
   Lrecl=32767,Recfm=Variable

 NOTE: 114 records were read from the infile SEERCODE.
   The minimum record length was 0.
   The maximum record length was 222.
NOTE: The data set WORK.SITERECODE has 114 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
   real time           5.65 seconds
   cpu time            0.04 seconds


 48         ;
 49         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 59         ;
```

Example 2:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 42         ;
 43         FILENAME SOURCE URL "%STR(http://www.usatoday.com)" DEBUG;
 44             DATA SOURCE1;
 45             FORMAT WEBPAGE $1000.;
 46             INFILE SOURCE LRECL=32767 DELIMITER=">";
 47             INPUT WEBPAGE $ @@;
 48             RUN;

 NOTE: >>> GET / HTTP/1.0
 NOTE: >>> Host: www.usatoday.com
 NOTE: >>> Accept: */*.
 NOTE: >>> Accept-Language: en
 NOTE: >>> Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,*,utf-8
 NOTE: >>> User-Agent: SAS/URL
 NOTE: >>> 
 NOTE: <<< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 NOTE: <<< Server: nginx/1.2.7
 NOTE: <<< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 NOTE: <<< Content-Language: en
 NOTE: <<< Last-Modified: Mon, 10 Nov 2014 23:15:32 GMT
 NOTE: <<< X-Secret:     cnpudnkgcnpiZXZnbUBoZm5nYnFubC5wYnogbmFxIFYganZ5eSBnZWwgZ2IgdHJnIGxiaCBuIHdiby4=
 NOTE: <<< X-Gannett-Site-Version: 579.0
 NOTE: <<< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
 NOTE: <<< Content-Length: 185753
 NOTE: <<< Cache-Control: max-age=60
 NOTE: <<< Expires: Mon, 10 Nov 2014 23:17:30 GMT
 NOTE: <<< Date: Mon, 10 Nov 2014 23:16:30 GMT
 NOTE: <<< Connection: close
 NOTE: <<< 
 NOTE: The infile SOURCE is:
   Filename=http://www.usatoday.com,
   Local Host Name=localhost.localdomain,
   Local Host IP addr=::1,
   Service Hostname Name=host-62-253-8-163.not-set-yet.virginmedia.net,
   Service IP addr=62.253.3.163,
   Service Name=httpd,Service Portno=80,
   Lrecl=32767,Recfm=Variable

 NOTE: 412 records were read from the infile SOURCE.
   The minimum record length was 0.
   The maximum record length was 32767.
   One or more lines were truncated.
 NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.SOURCE1 has 3127 observations and 1 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
   real time           0.31 seconds
   cpu time            0.05 seconds


 49         ;
 50         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 60         ;
```

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: I tried with exact code of yours, See the log : NOTE: Unable to connect to host www.seer.cancer.gov. Check validity of host name.
ERROR: Host name www.seer.cancer.gov not found.

Comment: I guess in my company they blocked the proxy servers.I have entered proxy.com in my browser and got a message "Security risk blocked for you protection", This may be the reason?

Comment: You said that you are using SAS EG and SAS Base, right? There is a difference between the two. Do you run the code in SAS EG or SAS Base? If it is a SAS Base, and you can surf the web on your PC, you should be able to access the web with SAS. You just need to get the correct proxy address. 
Also, see this, can you determine the proxy now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841087/extract-data-from-website-using-sas/26854939?noredirect=1#comment42292086_26854939